# Error: Cannot load provider. Base type is '.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationProvider'

Tags: sitecore

Version: 8.0

It was working and all of sudden it started throwing this error.

Update Note: After installing fresh install of site core instance , it worked fine and I have created outside project to built site specific templates and used publish option visual studio to deploy outside project files to the site core website folder. It started failing.

Comment: Please read this article on asking good questions and then amend yours to meet the criteria http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @MartinDavies , I have gone through ask a question and I m familiar with Stack Overflow but I am new to SiteCore. I have provided the snapshots and it throws this error on the site core instance. I don't know what else I can provide. This is specific to SiteCore CMS and NOT .net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's really hard to answer without details, but I would suggest you to replace the bin of your website from a fresh Sitecore 8.

Comment: Sure I will try replacing bin so I have to install another instance. Is there any bin in the program files or anywhere sitecores stores the core dlls.. The reason i am asking, I may not be able to install another instance on the client server.  @Vikram what else details will be helpful please let me know as I am new to Site Core...

Comment: It got solved after replacing the web.config file from the fresh install. The issue was it got corrupted when outside project was built and it has it's own web.config, during the publish process the web.config from outside project replaced web.config in sitecore website folder.   Always delete or exclude the web.config during publish process to avoid replacing .

Comment: Yes when it comes to .config files, we should be careful.